# Can not connect to MS SQL Server using JDBC driver SQLState 08001

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a MS SQL Server database using Java but I keep running into the same error.

I am using MS SQL Server for developers and am maniging it through SSMS. When I installed it I set is so it would use my windows credentials as password.

The JDBC driver is added to my project as a Maven dependency.

From what I understand reading the Microsoft doc's I should be able to use the following connection string:

```
String connectionUrl ="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;integratedSecurity=true";
```

However this does not seem to work for me as it returns SQLState 08001. After reading up on this state I understand that it has something to do with failing to make the connection.

I also tried to form my connection string using my windows login name, which results in the same:

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver:localhost:1433;databaseName=DBNAME;user=John Doe;password=0123456789";
```

I also tried to create a login using T-SQL to use as credentials using the same string as the previous (only changing the username and password):

```
CREATE ROLE [USER]
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON SCHEMA :: [dbo] TO USERNAME
CREATE LOGIN USERNAME_LOGIN WITH PASSWORD = '1234567890'
CREATE USER USER_USERNAME FROM LOGIN USERNAME_LOGIN
ALTER ROLE [USER] ADD MEMBER USER_USERNAME
```

I could really use some help to understand what I am doing wrong and what I can do to make it work. If you require me to check anything please let me know how as I am still pretty new to this.

**Edit**

As requested here is the info coming from getMessage():

> No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:sqlserver:localhost:1433;databaseName=.....

I am guessing this would also be the moment to mention the Maven dependency I am importing:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
<dependency>
       <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
       <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
       <version>7.3.0.jre8-preview</version>
</dependency>
```

I think the question now becomes, do I have the wrong driver as a dependency for MS SQL Server 2017?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the complete error message. "SQLState 08001" itself is not enough to adequately describe the problem.

Comment: Thanks you for the reply. I just edited my post and your comment helped a lot in pointing me into the right direction. Would you know how to verify if I have the correct driver as is stated now in my post?

Comment: Are you using an IDE? If so, which one? Eclipse? NetBeans? IntelliJ IDEA? ...?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate (student license).

Comment: Your URL is not valid for Microsoft SQL Server. Please read [their documentation on constructing a proper JDBC URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: The error message you posted shows `jdbc:sqlserver:localhost ...`, not `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost ...`. Are the slashes in your connection string or not?

Comment: Appoligies the error is given with the string "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DB_NAME;=USER_USErname;password=210500"

Comment: Please update your question with the actual code and error used, as it stands the question still suggests it is just a typo.

Comment: I found out my problem was that I did not enabled TCP/IP connection to the database (still pretty new to this). I will add this as a answer for those who are new and end up running into the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I turned out I did not had TCP/IP connections enabled for MS SQL Server.

To enable this in MS SQL Server 2017:

- Start SQLServerManager14.msc from the windows application menu.
- Go to SQL Server Network Configuration.
- Go to Protocols for YOURINSTANCE.
- Set TCP/IP to enabled.